# Problem with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw graphs with Gnuplot. But when I click the button for the example plot `sin (x)`, the gnuplot command window does not appear. I don't know the cause of that behavior

Comment: What "button for the example plot" exactly? Are you using some kind of GUI wrapper program for gnuplot? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

[`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a command-line program; you have to run it in a terminal emulator. On Ubuntu the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is set to open a new terminal window by default, but you can of course also find the terminal emulator in the Dash (or main menu).

In the terminal window, you can simply type `gnuplot` to launch the gnuplot command prompt. In order to plot your example, sin(x), on the gnuplot prompt, you can simply type:

```
plot sin(x)
```

to obtain:

[image: screenshot showing the usage of gnuplot]

There is a great tutorial in the [Gnuplotting page](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-functions/)...

Answer (score 2):

I assume your problem might be not able to plot using **Gnuplot** after installing. Because I too was unable to plot after installing it initially.

then from here [gnuplot not showing the graph window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277363/gnuplot-not-showing-the-graph-window/277369#277369)  I found solution that I need to install **gnuplot-x11**

so install it by running this command in *terminal* and see

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

after that run

```
  gnuplot
```

then on the gnuplot prompt you can run

```
  plot sin(x)
```

and see graph